# How to lookup EJB 3.1 inside an EAR running in Weblogic?

Tags: jndi, ejb-3.1, weblogic12c

I can lookup EJB using the following way when I deploy EJB as a seperate component in Weblogic 12c.

```
ctx.lookup("EJBImpl#com.xyz.EJBSendQ");
```

How can I lookup the same EJB when I put it inside an EAR. Let's say for example,

- main-application.ear

  - webservice.war
  - ejb.jar

Answer (score 1):

Now, I included my ejb component inside war file and I lookup in the following way,

```
EJBSendQ sendQ = (EJBSendQ) ctx.lookup("java:module/EJBSendQImpl")
```

So this is how we lookup our EJB If we put local enterprise bean within same module,

```
java:module/enterprise bean name/[interface name]
```

Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html